# UNIX Signal lost

Tags: signals

Is there any situation in which classic UNIX signals are lost?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious here. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 4):

Just after an identical signal has been received, before the handler has had time to reinstall itself, is an example. Generally speaking, when signals are arriving too quickly, some can be lost. Transmission of one signal is usually reliable but a million in one second is not.